# react-dom js file not loading properly in LWC

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, react

I am trying to import react and react-dom js file from static resource. i have usded the below cdn to collect the js file into static resource

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/cjs/react.production.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js

when i am importing react-dom js in LWC, its skipping below block. Any idea where i am doing wrong.

```
 Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, react),
        loadScript(this, reactdom),
    ]).then(() => { /* callback */
        this.error = undefined;
        this.showSuccessMessage();
        reactdom.render(react.createElement('div', null, `Hello React`), this.template.querySelector('react-root'));
    });
```

LWC -

```
import react from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/react';
import reactdom from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/reactdom';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';


    async connectedCallback() {
        //load react & react-dom
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, react),
            loadScript(this, reactdom),
        ]).then(() => { /* callback */
            this.error = undefined;
            this.showSuccessMessage();
            reactdom.render(react.createElement('div', null, `Hello React`), this.template.querySelector('react-root'));
        });
     }
```

Comment: So it's just not being called? What should be calling connectedCallback ?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn connectedCallback is a Web Component standards method that is called when the component is first placed in the DOM. The framework itself (Aura) or the browser calls this method.

Comment: good to know, thanks for the insight @sfdcfox

Comment: For some reason it does skip it with development version only while it is perfectly fine and working with the production minified version.